# Find all numbers between [i,j] which have lowest common divisor 'D'

Tags: numbers, sieve-of-eratosthenes

We need to find all numbers between [i,j] (inclusive) which have 'D' as it's lowest common divisor(LCD).

**Constraints** : 1<=i<=j<=2*10^9; 1<=D<=2*10^9;

If the constraints hadn't been that much large, it can be trivially solved using sieve of Eratosthenes.

Any solution to this problem is appreciated.

Comment: At FactHacks there's an algorithm for a [batched gcd computation](http://facthacks.cr.yp.to/batchgcd.html), i.e. computing the gcd for sequences of numbers faster than doing pairwise gcds or factoring.

Perhaps the techniques it uses can be adapted to your problem. Is this a competition puzzle or a practical problem?

Comment: Thnx for your input. It is a competition puzzle. BTW if you read carefully it asks for lowest common divisor rather than greatest common divisor. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I thought the *techniques* and *approaches* used there could be helpful. However, this being a competition puzzle suggests that there must be a reasonably simple and elegant solution, and also that it is sufficient to find something that works within the time/memory constraints. I'd rephrase the problem as "numbers that are divisible by D and have no lower common divisor", assuming that this is indeed what's mean with "LCD". So you divide your numbers by D and verify that the gcd of the quotients is 1.

Comment: The problem still seems strangely ill-defined, in the sense that adding number x to your result set may exclude u, v, and w, whereas u coming first would exclude x and include v and w. If you have to find a maximal set then you have probably have to factor, or use dynamic programming.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. It says if u,v,w or any other number lies in between i and j and these numbers have LCD equal to D, then these numbers are in the result set. Order of them doesn't matter as u and v are independent numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that all numbers in the range [i,j] are to be considered, instead of merely *some* numbers drawn from that range. Otherwise, a number x that has many smaller factors besides D could be 'poisonous' in the sense that it would exclude all other multiples of D having at least one of those smaller factors common with it. If the numbers are presented in order then there is no ambiguity.